# battery charging on solar panel

Tags: solar-cell

I have a single solar panel of 40 amps and I want to charge 12 volt 40 amp battery. How many such batteries can I charge on this single solar panel, and should I connect more batteries in parallel or in series? On these batteries I am going to use a 500 Watt inverter, so also should I connect more batteries in parallel or in series to the inverter? If I use two batteries then how much time will it take to charge?

Comment: That solar panel outputs 40 amps at what voltage?

Comment: Whether to put the batteries in series or parallel will depend on the voltage required by the inverter - the combined batteries must provide that voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The solar panel will run at a certain voltage,  probably 12 or 24 volts.  Your battery pack has to match the voltage of your solar panel.  When you put batteries in series, the voltage increase, but amp hours stays the same.  So if your solar panel is 24 volts, you want two 12 volt batteries in series to get a matching 24 volts.

Time to charge the batteries will depend on the amount of sunlight you have, capacity of your batteries, and amount of amps your panel can supply.   We don't have enough information to answer this question.  You mention a 40 amp solar panel which sounds quite high, you also mention a 40 amp hour battery.  Theoretically you would think it would take one hour to charge the battery, but you can't charge a lead acid battery that quickly without damaging it.

So we need to know the voltage of you solar panel and need to check the amps of your panel as well, then you can get better answers.